# Set up local FTP Server Using FileZilla

Tags: filezilla, ftp

I want to set up my desktop computer with FileZilla server so that I can connect to it on my laptop via FTP using FileZilla client. I do not want to make the server accessible outside of my internet connection, so I am assuming that opening a port on my router is not necessary. How can I do this?

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0veLA.png]

Comment: Just install FileZilla server on your desktop and then use a FTP client like FileZilla client to connect to it, and you are right, you don't need to open up a port in your router if you only want to have it available in your internal network. You can connect to it using it's internal ip.

Comment: @Alex Can anyone point me towards a good online tutorial on how to do this? I have looked online, and nothing that I try works.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: @Alex http://lifehacker.com/339887/build-a-home-ftp-server-with-filezilla and a few other ones with similar instructions. I can't get the Client on my laptop to connect.

Comment: And to which IP address do you connect? Are you sure, it's not blocked by a firewall or anything?

Comment: @Alex See ipconfig screenshot. I have tried 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.1, 127.0.0.1, & whatismyip.com gives me 108.32.45.47. This ipconfig screenshot is from my laptop, but I think the information should be the same regardless of which computer it comes from.

Comment: You need the ipv4 address from your desktop PC. Run ipconfig overthere, write down the ip goto your laptop and connect to that one.

Comment: @Alex is that the one that whatismyip.com gives me?

Comment: No, that is your internet IP from your internet modem. The address should be 192.168.1.x (not 3 because that is your laptop)

Comment: @Alex It worked, but I keep getting a "425 Can't open data connection." error, and the directory listing fails.